# Problem in converting digit image to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, mnist

I am practicing with the MNIST digit dataset.
I was excited to make any method for converting my hand written digits to numpy array. But was not getting the expected result.
Here's what I have written in photoshop:
[image: Image of 8 written in photoshop]

[image: Image of 7 written in photoshop]

Then I have written a code that convert the png image to np array that looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
img  =Image.open('New Project (11).png')
img_arr = np.array(img)
img_arr = img_arr.flatten()
img_arr = img_arr.astype('float64')
some_digit = img_arr.reshape(28,28)

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(some_digit,cmap='binary')
```

The result given was like this:

[image][image]

What wrong have I done or what is other easy alternative. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest posting the 28x28 source images rather than screenshots of the photoshop window. The problem can't be reproduced without the original source images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The numpy array that I have converted from the image is actually correct. For some reason it shows different. I have used skimage instead of PIL and inverted the image and it worked. The code is as follows:

```
import skimage.io as lo
from skimage import util 
img = lo.imread("New Project (16).png")
img = util.invert(img)
img_arr = np.array(img)
img_arr = img_arr.flatten()

# type(img_arr)
img_arr = img_arr.astype('float64')

some_digit = img_arr.reshape(28,28)
# some_digit = np.invert(some_digit)
# some_digit

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some_digit = X[0]
# some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,28)

plt.imshow(some_digit,cmap='binary')
```